# Rotate group of 3D CSS objects around group's center

Tags: css, rotation, center

I have built 3 little cubes in CSS and grouped them in a line within a div #first_line_of_cubes at the very bottom of CSS file. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVVK3/ (I think it works only in Chrome, since there aren't all the neccesary prefixes)

Now I want to rotate the line #first_line_of_cubes by using:

```
-webkit-transform:rotateY() rotate(x)
```

The problem is that ir rotates around left hand side corner of grouped cubes, but I want it to rotate around the center of grouped cubes.

So far Google said that solution is **-webkit-transform-origin** property, but I can't get any kind of effect with any values I have tried. What's the problem and how can I make it rotate around it's center?

If there isn't CSS solution, JavaScript/jQuery is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me it in Chrome version 27 setting the origin seems to work fine, although it seems like the center isn't quite where I think it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/MRpUb/

```
-webkit-transform-origin:300px 0px 0px;
```

Comment: I did some deeper investigation.
1.) Made another line of cubes under #second_line_of_cubes
2.) Turned off -webkit-perspective:1000px, so rotation on Y only can be seen on Y only (not also X).
3.) Positioned #second_line_of_cubes right right below #first_line_of_cubes
4.) Rotated #first_line_of_cubes by 0 degrees and #second_line_of_cubes by 180 degrees.

Now we can clearly see that rotation point isnt at center because they do not match.
However they match perfectly when transform-origin is set to "340px 0px 0px"
Heres what i'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/VpFjt/

Comment: So the question remains: where does those extra 40px came from? Logicly the value of 300px represents
the center of 600px wide line_of_cubes.

Comment: I believe it comes from the translateZ(XXpx);, because when you rotate if you do not correct for z translation the backface will be larger when brought to the front. It may not be the only thing but it could be part of what is causing the affect.